# CSS float - bottom corners

Tags: css, css-float

I have buttons that always float at the the bottom corner of the browser window.

The *back* button is in the correct place, but the *next* button won't float right.

```
#footerback {
    width: 107px;
    background-position: top;
    padding: 0px 30px 30px 0px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    float: left;    
}
#footernext {
    width: 107px;
    background-position: top;
    padding: 0px 30px 0px 30px;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0px;
    float: right;   
}
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: show a screenshot so we know exactly what you are seeing, and what is wrong...

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try this CSS to put it at bottom right;

```
position:fixed;
right:0;
bottom:0;
```

Comment: Very cool! Why doesn't BOTTOM:0PX with FLOAT:RIGHT work, however? I was able to get another element with POSITION:FIXED and FLOAT:RIGHT to go to the right TOP side of the page. But the bottom right corner was much trickier!

Comment: Can you give a full working example of this?

Answer (score 5):

Put your both buttons in another div, and apply a better css on this div:

```css
#footer {
    position:fixed;
    left:0;
    bottom:0;
}
#footerback,
#footernext {
    text-align: center;        
    width: 50px;
    float: left;
    border: 1px solid black;      
}
```

```html
<div id="footer">
    <div id="footerback">back</div>
    <div id="footernext">next</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

HTML

```
<div class="circle-div"></div>
```

CSS

```
.circle-div {
    background-color: #314963;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    border-radius: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 21px;
    right: 25px;
}
```

This places a round circle around the bottom right of the page.

Comment: please add some description to your answer which should point the user towards his mistake and also why should he use above, it prevents your answers from appearing into **Low Quality Posts**

Comment: Thanks, it's a very simple solution

Comment: @SanjayAchar great. Enjoy

Answer (score 2):

This will work
`position:fixed; right:0px; bottom:0; margin:0px; padding:0px;`

Answer (score 0):

You're saying to your elements that they need a FIXED position. Then you add css where you say that they can float on the page. The right answer is: say exactly where they need to be. Like Safraz did!